# Issue in Getting the tweets of whom I follow using twitter API

Tags: apache-flex, twitter, flash-builder, httpservice

I am using Twitter API and Flex 4 for creating Desktop App. I need to show tweets in two parts:
1)Tweets of User ABC to be shown in one section.
2)The tweets of people whom the User ABC is following, to be shown in another section.

#### I achieved point 1 by using :

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?&screen_name="+ usrObj.username + "&count=" + usrObj.count;

But getting Bad Authentication Error while trying for point no.2.

I am hitting the following URL using **HTTPSERVICE**:

**https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json**

Also, I used:

**https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.xml?&screen_name="+ usrObj.username + "&count=" + usrObj.count;**

where **usrObj is an object**.

Getting the following error message:

**Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json" errorID=2032**

Please let me know whether I am following proper url and queries. Can anyone suggest me as to how to get the tweets exactly?

Comment: Double-check that your API is still valid. Twitter turned most of it off the in the last few days.

Comment: Checked now.It is appropriate.But m unable to find the error code #215 in **[twitter API issues](https://dev.twitter.com/issues)** or **[twitter developer Discussions](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions)**

Comment: Kindly let me know why my question is downvoted?
I am new to twitter and i am trying all ways.i have asked a little help and people are downvoting instead of helping; without even giving reason as to what is missing in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my work done by using the following url for retrieving home timeline:

**https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/following_timeline.xml**